# How to call c# method after js function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

When I update the Input Text field in a web forms application with the javascript method, the change method in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code does not work.
How can I do that?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Value1" Columns="2" MaxLength="3" Text="1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Value1_TextChanged"/>
    
    <button onclick="changeText()">sample</button>
    <script>
    function changeText(){
       $("input[id$='Value1']").val("Change Value!");
    }
    
    </script>
``
```

And this page's cs side:

```
protected void Value1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string test="this works";
            }
```

How does the `Value1_TextChanged` method work in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) after the `changeText` method works in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably best to just do this:

```
        Js change text box<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="262px"
            onchange="mytextboxchange(this)"
            ></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdText7" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static"
            OnClick="cmdText7_Click" style="display:none"
            />
        <script>

            function mytextboxchange(btn) {

                console.log("client side text 7 runs")
                $('#cmdText7').click()

            }
```

And then you have code behind as

```
    protected void cmdText7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Server side text 7 changed");
    }
```

you could try a __doPostBack("Mytext7","")

But, if there are no controls on the page that need/have a post-back, then the _doPostBack() stub is not automatic added, and it gets messay.

So, just drop in a button. Add the button click event, then hide it with display:none, and you done. You don't have to do a text changed event that often, so above will should suffice.

Comment: Thansk for answer. I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: The click event example works as posted and has been tested code. I used this approach for years. I do of course assume jQuery. And NOTE VERY careful how I set ClientIDModel="static" for the text box (this makes the jQuery selector simple and easy to use. As I stated, you "can" use a __DoPostBack, but on some pages it will not work since the __DoPostBack() is not automatic injected into that page. Either approach is fine, but the posted code does work, but does assume you have jQuery installed and working (don't we all??).

Answer (score 0):

Since programmatically changing the value of an input doesn't fire its change event, so you need to trigger change event manually to make it post back to server side event. You could update your `changeText` function like this

```
function changeText(){
   $("input[id$='Value1']").val("Change Value!");
   // trigger event change manually
   $("input[id$='Value1']").trigger("change");
}
```

Comment: Thansk for answer. I tried this but it didn't work.